# Does the vote in favor of Article 13 affect Stack Exchange?

Tags: european-union, copyright

The EU parliament voted in favor of Article 13. An article which is heavily disputed and may have huge impacts on sites publishing (even if they are small) images or videos of others' creative work. My question is: is Stack Exchange maybe affected by this, considering there are a lot of images and short extracts of movies, comics, series and other media for example in the [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) or [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Should this be in Meta StackExchange?

Comment: If it potentially affects YouTube, why not also StackExchange?

Comment: Related question on Meta Stack Exchange: [EU's article 13 will heavily censor the web. Should we do something?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324866/295232)

Comment: The answer is simply yes (compare with [the GDPR precedent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308491/how-is-stack-exchange-preparing-for-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr), but the question is off-topic here, IMO. At best it might be a law.SE question, but probably just meta.SE.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: Because a part of the final version of the article is apparently a list of somewhat arbitrary exceptions of platforms and content subject to the article.

Comment: How a law affects a specific apolitical website is not a political question. This question belongs on either https://law.stackexchange.com or https://meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score -4):

Stack exchange is a US-based company. While the General Data Protection Regulation (or GDPR) is an EU-wide law that protects Europeans with regards to the processing of their personal data, including data processed in the US, I would be not be inclined to believe that all EU regulations have a blanket requirement to be upheld in the US, just as US regulations, (aside from any specific laws that might protect US citizens globally,) are required to be upheld anywhere besides the US.

Comment: That’s not how international law works. StackExchange does business in the EU, and are subject to EU law regardless of where they’re “based”.